# Load Fragment only when Tab clicked

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I want my fragment to load only when the tab is clicked. That is I am calling a webservice on each fragment, so I want that webservice to be called only when user clicks the specific tab; loads the fragment.

My Fragments are attached to the view pager.

I have override the following method in my fragments: **setUserVisibleHint**

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isFragmentVisible: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(true)

        if (this.isVisible) {
            // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
            if (isFragmentVisible && !isLoadOnce) {
                callAPI(param)
                isLoadOnce = true
            }
        }
    }
```

the variable is set as:     **private var isLoadOnce = false** in the fragment class.

I have 3 fragments in number the problem is when my activity popsup, the first fragment is visible and if I click the last tab that is the third tab to load the third fragment, nothing happens that is the web service won't call at all.

But when I click the second fragment and then the third fragment, and yes the webservice then only calls

So I want to call the web service whenver the user clicks each fragment (number 2 fragment or number 3 fragment)!
Can somebody please figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Call "callApi(param)" on onResume() of the fragment;
2. Override [onPageSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onpageselected)(int) and call "callApi(param) in it.

Let me know if this worked for you!

Answer (score -1):

viewpager generally loads the side views to provide smooth swipe experience.

you can restrict the viewpager to load the view using

```
  viewpager.setOffScreenLimit(0)
```